# If $\alpha$ is the lower bound of $E$ and $\beta$ is the upper bound of $E$, show that $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

From Baby Rudin:

> Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of an ordered set; suppose $\alpha$ is a lower bound  of $E$ and $\beta$ is an upper bound of $E$. Prove that $\alpha \leq \beta$.

My approach:

Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the lower and upper bounds respectively. Then:
$\forall x \in E$, $\alpha \leq x$
$\forall x \in E$, $x \leq \beta$

So let $z\in E$, then $\alpha \leq z$ and $z \leq \beta$, and as it's an ordered set, this implies $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes. (Note that "So let $z\in E$" is the point where you use the given that $E$ is nonempty)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Essential is the existence of some $z\in E$.

Comment: Note the difference between the title (incorrectly stated) and the question. In general, upper and lower bounds are not unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you can ommit the $\forall x \in E, \alpha \leq x$ and $\forall x \in E, x \leq \beta$. Just write:

> As $E$ is nonempty, we may choose an element $z$. As $\alpha$ is a lower bound, $\alpha \leq z$, and as $\beta$ is an upperbound, $z \leq \beta$. By transitivity:
>
> $$\alpha \leq z \text{ and } z \leq \beta \implies \alpha \leq \beta$$

(Note, you should mention the existence of some $z$. I would also, say "by transitivity" to further clarify the last step)